# Using Trigger to update database when insert is used

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Im looking for a way to use triggers to update a row in a different table. 
The table im trying to get the info from is AI (Auto increment) and also the primary key of that table.

My problem is that i cant find a simple way of doing it.

My code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Konsistens;
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER Konsistens AFTER INSERT ON PersonData
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Bruker(BrukerNavn, Passord, PersonId)
 VALUES('Bruker1', 'pw1', LAST_INSERT_ID(PersonData.PersonID));
END
```

All i want is for PersonID to be given a value inside the Bruker table. 
Since PersonID is a foreign key from Person to Bruker it doesnt seem to exist when i try to get the value from it. When i use this trigger it also creates a bug where i can no longer insert values into PersonData.
My desired result is that when you insert something into PersonData you get a new row into Bruker which have the same PersonID as the new entry in PersonData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just reference recenty inserted row by **NEW**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Konsistens 
 AFTER INSERT ON PersonData
FOR EACH ROW
 INSERT INTO Bruker (BrukerNavn, Passord, PersonId)
 VALUES(NEW.BrukerNavn, NEW.Passord, NEW.PersonId);
```

Comment: When I use new i get an error saying it cant find the table called NEW.BrukerNavn. It seems it's trying to create a new table and not update the one i have. This happens when i INSERT values into PersonData.

Comment: Okay i fixed it.. Turns out i was just using the wrong syntax. The right one was 
    NEW.'PersonID'

Comment: So this is Okay for you ? by the way, the syntax in the ansewer is correct according to mysql standards. If this is not the case you can edit the ansewer and after that mark it as the correct one. cheers